# What is the sum of the following series? Is it some extended Zeta function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

What is the sum of the following series?
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\nu)_m}{m!}\frac{1}{(m+1)^s}$$

where $(\nu)_m=\frac{\Gamma(\nu+m)}{\Gamma(\nu)}=\nu\cdot(\nu+1)\cdots(\nu+n-1))$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

Comment: For what $s$ does it converge ?

Comment: For \Re{(s-\nu)}>1

Comment: Is it the Mellin transform of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {-\nu \choose m} (-1)^m e^{-(m+1)x}  = e^{-x}(1-e^{-x})^{-\nu}$ or something related ?

Comment: Yes, it is, but I can't solve the integral.

Comment: The poles of $\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-x} (1-e^{-x})^{-\nu}dx$ are given by the expansion of $e^{-x} (1-e^{-x})^{-\nu}$ at $x= 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to find the general solution of $$A_s=\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{ \Gamma (m+\nu )}{m! \,\Gamma (\nu )}\frac 1{(m+1)^{s}}$$ but it is almost sure that polylogarithm functions would be involved.

Using a CAS, what I got is $$A_1=\frac{1}{1-\nu }$$ $$A_2=\frac{\psi ^{(0)}(2-\nu )+\gamma }{1-\nu}$$ $$A_3=\frac{6 \psi ^{(0)}(2-\nu )^2+12 \gamma  \psi ^{(0)}(2-\nu )-6 \psi ^{(1)}(2-\nu
   )+\pi ^2+6 \gamma ^2}{12 (1-\nu)}$$ and, for $s>3$, the expressions start to be really nasty.